# fondo color con display inline

Tags: html, css3

```css
section{
 width:1300px;
 height: 350px;
 display: inline;
}

#img1 figcaption{
 text-align: center;
}

section #segsection{
 width: 1300px;
 height: 300px;
 display: inline;
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div id="img1">
    <figure>
     <img class="foto" src="imagenes/foto.jpg">
    <figcaption>Dibujo dibujo</figcaption>
    </figure>
 </div>
</section>

<section id="segsection">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi excepturi possimus voluptates accusamus, sed quasi dolore esse labore repudiandae, necessitatibus, ducimus iure iste deserunt expedita quo ea voluptatem. Numquam, magnam?</p>
</section>
```

¿Cómo puedo poner color de fondo con un display inline?

No quiero cambiar el display porque no quiero que me haga salto de línea, o sea que inblick o me sirve.

Comment: Fundo de color y display son 2 cosas muy diferentes. Puedes dar un poco mas de detalles con codigo de ejemplo?

Comment: Puse dos section con display inline para que no haga salto de línea y no me coge el background, no sé si me explico.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que eliminar el espacio entre el "section" y el identificador "#segsection". De la otra forma, estás indicando que el elemento con id=segsection debe ser un hijo del "section".

Además, el color se lo debes aplicar al elemento p hijo del section, de la siguiente forma.

```css
section{
 width:1300px;
 height: 350px;
 display: inline;
}

#img1 figcaption{
 text-align: center;
}

section#segsection{
 width: 1300px;
 height: 300px;
 display: inline;

}

section#segsection p{
    background-color: yellow;

}
```

```html
<section>
 <div id="img1">
    <figure>
     <img class="foto" src="imagenes/foto.jpg">
    <figcaption>Dibujo dibujo</figcaption>
    </figure>
 </div>
</section>

<section id="segsection">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi excepturi possimus voluptates accusamus, sed quasi dolore esse labore repudiandae, necessitatibus, ducimus iure iste deserunt expedita quo ea voluptatem. Numquam, magnam?</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el div al tener `display: inline` no ocupa espacio, tienes dos opciones:

1. Cambiar a `display: inline-block`, de esta forma te respetará el alto y el ancho que tu estás declarando

```css
section {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#img1 figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}

section#segsection {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="img1">
    <figure>
      <img class="foto" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/nature/">
      <figcaption>Dibujo dibujo</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="segsection">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi excepturi possimus voluptates accusamus, sed quasi dolore esse labore repudiandae, necessitatibus, ducimus iure iste deserunt expedita quo ea voluptatem. Numquam, magnam?</p>
</section>
```

2. Decirle a tu elemento `p` que herede el color de fondo de su padre

```css
section {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 350px;
  display: inline;
}

#img1 figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}

section#segsection {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #FF0;
}

section#segsection p {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="img1">
    <figure>
      <img class="foto" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/nature/">
      <figcaption>Dibujo dibujo</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="segsection">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi excepturi possimus voluptates accusamus, sed quasi dolore esse labore repudiandae, necessitatibus, ducimus iure iste deserunt expedita quo ea voluptatem. Numquam, magnam?</p>
</section>
```

Por último si tu elemento y su id están al mismo nivel debes ponerlos juntos de esta forma: `section#segsection`, y si quieres que tu código sea responsivo es mejor declarar un `max-width` en lugar de `width`

```css
section {
  max-width: 1300px;
  height: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#img1 figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}

section#segsection {
  max-width: 1300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="img1">
    <figure>
      <img class="foto" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/nature/">
      <figcaption>Dibujo dibujo</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="segsection">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi excepturi possimus voluptates accusamus, sed quasi dolore esse labore repudiandae, necessitatibus, ducimus iure iste deserunt expedita quo ea voluptatem. Numquam, magnam?</p>
</section>
```